# Clean way to iterate a dictionary in Python

Tags: python-3.x, loops, numpy, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has the following `structure` :

```
d = {0: [array(), array(), array(), ..]
     1: [array(), array(), array(), ..]
     2: [array(), array(), array(), ..]}
```

What is the best way to iterate over this type of dictionary? I want to append values and print all the arrays (separately) along with `dict` keys.

The output should be something like this :

```
0 []
0 []
.
.
1 []
1 []
.
.
2 []
2 []
.
.
```

Comment: showing your desired output is going to be more effective than describing it.

Comment: This data structure is bizarre. Why does it look like this? Why a dict, if the keys are just going to be an increasing sequence of ints? Why lists of arrays inside the dict? Why not just a single higher-dimensional array, or if the inner lists aren't the same length, why not a list of lists of arrays?

Comment: There are standard ways of iterating on a Python dictionary.  That fact that the values are lists of arrays doesn't change that.

Comment: What is **array()** here in your code?

Comment: Each array() is 1d array of floats.